# Parsing datetime64 and datetime.time Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

> I have two columns, one has type datetime64 and datetime.time. The
>   first column has  the day and the second one the hour and minutes. I
>   am having trouble parsing them:

```
Leistung_0011

       ActStartDateExecution ActStartTimeExecution
0             2016-02-17              11:00:00
10            2016-04-15              07:15:00
20            2016-06-10              10:30:00
```

Leistung_0011['Start_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(Leistung_0011['ActStartDateExecution'].astype(str) + ' ' + Leistung_0011['ActStartTimeExecution'].astype(str))

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'NaT 00:00:00')
```

Comment: We can't help you without an example of your dataframe (`Leistung_0011`). You should also include the full traceback.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you post your data?

Comment: Yes, excuse me, this is my first post in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to `str` and join with whitespace before passing to `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str))

print(df, df.dtypes, sep='\n')

#          day      time            datetime
# 0 2018-01-01  15:00:00 2018-01-01 15:00:00
# 1 2015-12-30  05:00:00 2015-12-30 05:00:00
# day         datetime64[ns]
# time                object
# datetime    datetime64[ns]
# dtype: object
```

**Setup**

```
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['2018-01-01', '2015-12-30'],
                   'time': ['15:00', '05:00']})

df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'])
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M').time())

print(df['day'].dtype, type(df['time'].iloc[0]), sep='\n')

# datetime64[ns]
# <class 'datetime.time'>
```

---

Complete example including seconds:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""       ActStartDateExecution ActStartTimeExecution
0             2016-02-17              11:00:00
10            2016-04-15              07:15:00
20            2016-06-10              10:30:00""")

df = pd.read_csv(x, delim_whitespace=True)

df['ActStartDateExecution'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ActStartDateExecution'])
df['ActStartTimeExecution'] = df['ActStartTimeExecution'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S').time())
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ActStartDateExecution'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['ActStartTimeExecution'].astype(str))

print(df.dtypes)

ActStartDateExecution    datetime64[ns]
ActStartTimeExecution            object
datetime                 datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I tried converting it to str, but I am still getting this error: Leistung_0011['Start_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(Leistung_0011['ActStartDateExecution'].astype(str) + ' ' + Leistung_0011['ActStartTimeExecution'].astype(str)) ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'NaT 00:00:00')

Comment: @DiegoLainfiesta, This isn't enough to fix your issue. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Excuse me...is my first time. Here is a copy of the data set:    ActStartDateExecution ActStartTimeExecution
0             2016-02-17              11:00:00
10            2016-04-15              07:15:00
20            2016-06-10              10:30:00 Leistung_0011['Start_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(Leistung_0011['ActStartDateExecution'].astype(str) + ' ' + Leistung_0011['ActStartTimeExecution'].astype(str)) ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'NaT 00:00:00')

Comment: No problem. But please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51929238/edit) with properly formatted code, don't put code in comments, it's unreadable.

Comment: Done...in the original post... :)